# Unnecessary white space around project when running

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on a small, single page c# UWP application. When I look at it in the design view everything looks okay, there's no unnecessary white space. But when I run it the window has a large border of empty space around the entire design and it looks terrible. Below I've included screenshots of the design and the running window. How can I remove this excess white space?

Design view (no weird white space):

[image: Design view, no weird white space]

Running (weird white space):

[image: Running, weird white space]

The application window is fairly small, 400x200. I've tried changing these values but all it does is squish the controls together and add even more white space around the border.

Edit: Apparently despite the design view being fine it's a problem with my XAML, so here you go.

```
<Page x:Class="ReservationManager.Views.StartPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:ReservationManager.Views"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      DataContext="{Binding StartPageInstance, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
      Width="400"
      Height="200">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="Label1"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Label 1: "
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI Historic" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Name="TextBox1"
                     MaxLength="7"
                     Text="{Binding tb1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Name="Label2"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Label 2: "
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI Historic" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Name="TextBox2"
                     Text="{Binding tb2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Name="Label3"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Label 3: "
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI Historic" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Name="Dropdown"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding cb}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding cb1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1">
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsReserveChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         GroupName="Radio"
                         Content="radio1" />
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsUnreserveChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         GroupName="Radio"
                         Content="radio2" />
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Red">
            Warning: ----
        </TextBlock>

        <Button Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="Execute"
                Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure of what you want here, but the grid takes all the space available, and given your layout and the fact the controls are all align in the center of each grid cell, blank space between them should be expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was being caused by the "preferred minimum size" being set too high by default.

Adding the below line to the code behind fixed the issue:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size { Width = 250, Height = 200 });
```